# Flutter doctor warns about Dart's path after upgrading to Flutter version 3.7.0

Tags: ios, flutter, zshrc, flutter-doctor

After upgrading Flutter to version 3.7.0, this following warning persists from Flutter doctor. I have tried everything but the problem still remains. Anything I can do?

Flutter doctor warns on Dart path

[image: Flutter doctor warns on Dart path]

I added dart to the right path and everything was working well before upgrading. I was expecting no issues at all.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by removing dart from homebrew!

```
brew remove dart
```

Comment: Installing Dart via homebrew was indeed the cool thing to do if you didn't want flutter, or before flutter had a complete dart sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I also fixed it by uninstalling homebrew dart.

```
brew remove dart
```